# Which area has more research scope: neural networks or cryptography?

Tags: phd, mathematics, computer-science, career-path

I am from Mathematics Background. I am getting an offer to a phd in cryptography but am also thinking of going in deep learning theory- which area has more scope in future in research?

Answer (score 1):

Both are pretty hot at the moment and will likely stay hot for a while, but the future remains unknown to us. Some truly key breakthrough in a field can quiet interest in it, or expand it.

But you will have an opportunity to re-examine the question over the course of a career and make judgements about whether to continue a line of research or move to another.

A decision made now isn't necessarily a "forever" decision.

"Prediction is hard. Especially about the future." ([Source unknown](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/10/20/no-predict/))